# What does .change do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've come across the following the line of code:

```
self.update(next_question_at: (next_question_at.next_week).change(hour: 10))
```

I'm googling for the `change` method but cannot find the docs for it, what is the method doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It changes the hour value of the `DateTime` object returned by `next_question_at.next_week`.

Lets say you have this `2013-01-01 11:55:00`, if you apply a `change(hour:7)` it will become `2013-01-01 7:55:00`.

You can use any of this keys:

```
:year, :month, :day, :hour, :min, :sec, :offset, :start.
```

You can found the method documentation here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-change